# Detect when label appears on screen in SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I have a scroll view with several elements (textview, label, image view...), I need to display an uiview when my label appears on the screen when I'm scrolling.

How can I do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your view controller is the scroll view delegate. Implement the `scrollViewDidScroll` method, and check whether the scroll view's frame, offset by the contentOffset, overlaps the label's frame.

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let offset = self.scrollView.contentOffset
    let onScreen = CGRectOffset(self.scrollView.frame, offset.x, offset.y)
    if CGRectIntersectsRect(onScreen, self.label.frame) {
        NSLog("Overlap")
    }
}
```

If you want to detect when the label is fully on the screen, use `CGRectContainsRect` instead of `CGRectIntersectsRect`.